# SciPy minimize function with 'eq' constraints but not SLSQP algo (preferably GRG)

Tags: python, excel, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm working on converting an Excel solver to python using NumPy and SciPy and while I technically have it working I'm running into slight differences with the results.

Sample data being put through formula:

```
array_1 = [
  0.0943417538897551,
  0.0799476059590533,
  0.0486689860368342,
  0.052434296201351 ,
  0.231614207638357,
  0.0808322159046283,
  0.0819215585688325,
  0.140991841045595,
  0.189247534431047
]

matrix_1 = [
  [0.0235147682238835,    0.0194641686338689,    0.0116344823277316,    0.0214041868628604,    0.010980242438382,     0.013085897256736,     0.0107928914491097,      -0.000350116147653561, 0.000323182155233255],
  [0.0194641686338689,    0.0227374787807333,    0.0147128129866735,    0.023168038099643,     0.00899606198312112,   0.0108035747784655,    0.00989996824509696,     -0.000271072225966624, 0.000337765823991017],
  [0.0116344823277316,    0.0147128129866735,    0.0265282312707786,    0.0140689757522423,    0.021443195995926,     0.0252024393105442,    0.0187159868856209,      0.000969972826332724,  -0.0000408711850838449],
  [0.0214041868628604,    0.023168038099643,     0.0140689757522423,    0.0288819629130722,    0.00890430456025532,   0.00987603454385401,   0.00914278195359995,     -0.000127719476583381, 0.000340663672172775],
  [0.010980242438382,     0.00899606198312111,   0.021443195995926,     0.00890430456025532,   0.029544562002381,     0.0314280240062057,    0.017176083705661,       0.00103517056623238,   0.0000307234067635423],
  [0.013085897256736,     0.0108035747784655,    0.0252024393105442,    0.00987603454385401,   0.0314280240062057,    0.0552293560476392,    0.0198882118118466,      0.000830285068544538,  -0.000328125366438888],
  [0.0107928914491097,    0.00989996824509696,   0.0187159868856209,    0.00914278195359995,   0.017176083705661,     0.0198882118118466,    0.0174188411860936,      0.000638033896492422,  -0.00000837412076787606],
  [-0.000350116147653561, -0.000271072225966624, 0.000969972826332724,  -0.000127719476583381, 0.00103517056623238,   0.000830285068544538,  0.000638033896492422,    0.00207309710065845,   0.00038309084175021],
  [0.000323182155233255,  0.000337765823991017,  -0.0000408711850838449, 0.000340663672172775, 0.0000307234067635422, -0.000328125366438888, -0.00000837412076787614, 0.00038309084175021,   0.000315889643542944]
]

user_input_number = 0.2 # fluctuates between 0 and 1

array_2 = [
  0.0555192520462957,
  0.0521964263617645,
  0.0727151670043896,
  0.0541841497069959,
  0.0797919901829936,
  0.0972924758058667,
  0.057466786568159,
  0.00266000663087858,
  0.000440591301372533,
]
```

and my calculation function looks like this:

```
def calculate(array_1):
  step_one = np.dot(np.dot(array_1, matrix_1), array_1)
  step_two = user_input_number * np.dot(array_2, array_1)
  return step_one - step_two 

# matrix_1, array_2, and user_input_number are defined outside of this scope
```

The bounds on `array_1` numbers need to stay within 0 and 1:

```
myBounds = ((0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1))
```

and I need to pass a constraint, where the `sum(array_1)` would equal 1:

```
myConstraint = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  1 - sum(x)})
```

so my SciPy `minimize` call ends up something like this:

```
result = minimize(calculate, myArray, method="SLSQP", bounds=myBounds, constraints=myConstraint)

# 'SLSQP' is used because I read it is the only one that allows a constraint.
```

and like I mentioned this works, but not accurately to the results we are getting in Excel.

Here is a screen shot of the solver settings:

[image: excel solver]

and you can see it's using the solving method "GRG Nonlinear" but that option is not in the [minimize docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) under available methods. I saw 'BFGS' and 'L-BFGS-B' recommended which were much closer results but I couldn't do a great comparison since it did not allow for a constraint to be put on the resulting array.

My overall question would be what is the best way to replicate the "GRG Nonlinear" method of minimizing with a constraint?

Comment: *"while I technically have it working I'm running into slight differences with the results"* - what does that mean? Are the SLSQP solutions better, worse, or just different? It would help if you gave some example input data.

Comment: You might also try COBYLA, which also uses linear rather than quadratic approximations to the objective function (unlike SLSQP). All of the constraint functions must be of the form `f(x) >= 0`, but you can implement an equality constraint using a pair of such inequalities.

Comment: Edited to include same data, and I will try out the COBYLA algo, thanks. The differences between the Excel sheet and the program are as you said "just different". Sometimes the values would be higher, sometimes lower, sometimes barely off, sometimes off by like 10-20 percentage points.

Comment: If the SLSQP solutions are just as good then why would you care if they are different to the GRG ones?

Comment: Note that Excel's GRG code is not super precise, it has fairly loose tolerances and it may use finite difference gradients. Am I correct that you want to solve a quadratic portfolio optimization problem? In that case you can also look into specialized solvers like  [cvxopt](http://cvxopt.org/).

Comment: Still not clear if the 'differences' are in the details of the solution or the objective function value. If the solutions are similar but not identical they may both be valid. Many problems have internal symmetries that allow for many different detailed choices that are in fact equivalent. We usually try to impose one solver's solution on the other solver to 'prove' their equivalence, so in your case try forcing the Excel solver's solution on your new implementation, and vice versa. This can be as simple as adding (many) constraints like var1 = value1 etc.

Comment: @ali_m unfortunately the client did not think they were just as good, so I have to care haha. Someone else told us about some proprietary GRG ones so we may have to look into that more if they don't like the results we get with SciPy

Comment: In that case, do I need to interpret your requirement as being that the result must be *exactly* the same as that of the Excel GRG solver?

Comment: I don't think it needs to be _exactly_ the same as the Excel GRG solver, just much closer than what we were getting. Today I am changing the current program to run both SLSQP and COBYLA side by side to run a closer comparison, and then looking more at the cvxopt solver that was suggested.

Comment: @ali_m could you please provide an example of an inequality constraint pair using the format you mentioned earlier that gives the equivalent of the equality constraint where `sum(x) == 1`? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around that piece.

Comment: *"I don't think it needs to be exactly the same as the Excel GRG solver, just much closer than what we were getting."* I think you should talk to your client about this and pin down exactly what they would find acceptable. Unless you exactly recapitulated Excel's GRG solver it would be very difficult to make any general claims about the closeness of your solutions. You should make the case that it is the value of the objective function that counts, not how close the solution happens to be to Excel's. Suppose SLSQP consistently gave *better* solutions than Excel?

Comment: `({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  1 - sum(x)}, {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  -(1 - sum(x))})`